# Kali Linux gives me an error message when I try to use setup

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux

When I tried to setup Kali Linux, I got an error message saying that it can't find
 `win32-loader.ini`.

I also tried just booting it, but the CMD window pops-up only for a blink of an eye and I hadn't enough time to read it.

I saw a Notepad file named  `win32-loader.ini` in the Kali Linux file I made. I also tried running it from an USB that I have made bootable. I have tried looking it up but I couldn't find anything about the error I saw.

I am running Windows 8.